# Are things ever dialect checked?

Tags: word-choice, mandarin, topolect

I'm wondering if things (in general) are ever dialect checked?

哈尔滨啤酒 has a commercial where they go around singing the name 哈啤 over and over again but it sounds a lot like `SB` in Southwestern Mandarin. (They really should have checked that.)

I'm wondering if these public things (billboards, commercials, posters, etc.) are ever checked to make sure it doesn't have any dialectical problems?

Comment: Tones are different, I presume? As long as tones are different, it really doesn't matter. 沙壁 is a legit word, right?

Comment: Yeah, but singing...

Comment: 之前一直在电视广告上看见“一起哈啤”的广告，觉得非常不错！“哈啤”=“happy”，很棒！可是今天突然在成都大街上看见这个广告语，越看越不对！在四川，真心不应该放这个广告语！因为四川话中“hapi”是骂人的…[汗][汗][汗]“哈啤=hapi=哈批”，意思为“莽舅子，傻儿，瓜货，傻屌”@哈尔滨啤酒

Comment: A lot of words sound alike in Chinese, especially across dialects, and especially if you neglect tone.  And on the other hand, I see this ad campaign is looking for a funky feeling.  How do native speakers respond to it, as far as you know?  @倪阔乐 are you a native speaker?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty I saw you're deleted comment and posted something I found online talking about it

Comment: @ColinMcLarty here's another: 匿名用户 匿名用户
cnt，刚刚成为大学毕业班一员，想到大一去去乐山一哥们学校。肿么割。晚上去吃烧烤，想来点啤酒，就问老板问有什么啤酒。老板回句＂哈P＂顿时怒了，问个酒都被骂，站起来就怒道＂你说什么＂准备揍人了。结果老板才说＂哈啤，哈尔滨啤酒＂我。。。顿时hll的坐下了。四川话太霸道了-_-#

Comment: It's the name of the beer too

Comment: Your second example ends with 四川话太霸道了.  It blames the dialect, not the ad.  And it is *funny.*  哈尔滨啤酒 may like that response.

Comment: 霸道 is less blaming (at least in Sichuanese) and more like *awesome*

Comment: @user3306356  Thanks, I misread 霸道 .  So the beer company has all the more reason to like the passage you quote.

Comment: If you are dissatisfied with Wang Dingwei's answer, maybe you should clarify your question to say why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Once your sentence exceeds seven words, it is guaranteed that you will offend a man in the street or a women on the roof. So we just give it up.

Like the homophones in the same dialect aren't enough to deal with...

But if you are to do business in Sichuan (or anywhere actually) it's your own lookout.